# Stack overflow during compilation on large list literal in OCaml

Tags: list, compiler-errors, ocaml, code-generation, ocaml-dune

I have a small project for checking if a number is prime. The idea is to prepare (generate) a list of primes up to a certain point for the library function to use (use a code generator for that).

Whilst the code generation works fine, compilation of generated file fails if the list is large (for example for list of primes up to a million, that is ~75k entries).

Output of dune build:

[image]

Part (at the bottom) of output of dune build --verbose:[image]

Some code:

```
(* prime_list.mli *)
val long_list : int list
```

```
(* THIS FAILS TO COMPILE: prime_list.ml (was generated, found only in _build directory) *)
let long_list = [2;3;5;7;
<a lot more entries, depending on parameter provided in dune file...>]
```

As I understand, the list literal, (which is of course sugar for `2 :: (3 :: ( 5 :: ... )))` has too deeply nested calls to `::` and the stack overflows, during compilation (probably parsing rather than constructing the value? I don't know how the compilation works in OCaml at all sadly).

Do you have an idea for a way around that? I would like to have a list as long as I please, wrote every single function using tail recursion and the compiler is letting me down like this...

To recap: I have the list in memory (in generator) but am not able to dump it to a file (preferably .ml) in a way that allows me to bake it in the main program, which is frustrating.

Out of desperation I also tried generating a file like so:

```
(* prime_list.ml, another try *)
let long_list = []
let long_list = 999983 :: long_list
let long_list = 999979 :: long_list
...
let long_list = 3 :: long_list
let long_list = 2 :: long_list
```

as well as

```
let long_list0 = []
let long_list1 = 999983 :: long_list0
let long_list2 = 999979 :: long_list1
...
let long_list78487 = 3 :: long_list78496
let long_list78498 = 2 :: long_list78497
let long_list = long_list78498
```

but both these approcheas resulted in the same thing (`Fatal error: exception Stack overflow`). I am new to OCaml and I don't understand why exactly didn't this work. I am interested in an answer -- may be a bit of speculation -- to this question. Besides a solution to my problem of course.

Maybe I could change the limit of the stack somehow? Answers coming from this angle (of compiler settings and flags) will be much appreciated, but this wouldn't really be satisfactory as the final answer, as it probably doesn't scale indefinitely (I may be wrong here though, who knows?).

Here are lib/dune file contents for completeness:

```
; primes_with_generator/lib/dune
(library
 (name primes_with_generator)
 (libraries commons))

(rule
 (target prime_list.ml)
 (deps    (:gen ../generator/gen.exe))
 (action  (with-stdout-to %{target} (run %{gen} 1000000))))
```

1_000_000 is a parameter here -- primes up to 1_000_000 are generated. For primes generated up to 100_000 everything is fine, but I would like primes up to sqrt(INT MAX) ≈ 2^32 ≈ 10^9... well, at least wouldn't like to stop at ~200k because of a dumb reason like this.

Commons is probably irrelevant, but here is its interface for you to see:

```
(* commons/prime.mli *)

(* given arguments:
 - list of primes up to a point, should be in ascending order, may be empty),
 - a number n >= 2
   returns answer to the question: is number n prime?
*)
val is_prime : int list -> int -> bool
```

Comment: Use a `Bigarray.Array1` serialized to a file and read back in at runtime?

Comment: (`Unix.map_file` would come in handy for this approach)

Comment: It's an aside, but if you're using a list of known primes to test if an int is a prime, are you sure you want a list? Lookup will be O(n), vs. something like a hash table.

Comment: Or possible a set.

Comment: I am testing if n is divisible by them. With primes up to, say 100_000 I can check any number up to 10_000_000_000 is prime more efficiently (Currently for numbers bigger than max_p^2 the algorightm sometimes (if no small divisors found) checks divisibility by consecutive numbers after that). Also I don't even know how to do those things yet haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution to your issue is to increase stack size (with `ulimit -s unlimited` on linux or by switching to OCaml 5).

The scalable solution is to not mix code and data. Your table of prime number is data and should be stored as such. As a quick storage format, you could use the [`Marshal` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Marshal.html). If for some reason, you really don't want to have a separate data file, you can store your data as string:

```ml
let primes: int array =
  Marshal.from_string
    "\132\149\166\190\000\000\000\006\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\006\000\000\000\006\208BCEGK"
    0
```

which should work until the point where the array will be too big to keep fully in memory.

EDIT:
In order to load data from a file, you can use `In_channel.with_open_bin` which takes care of opening and closing the channel (even if an exception is raised) by itself

```
let load filename: int array =
  In_channel.with_open_bin filename @@ fun chan ->
  Marshal.from_channel chan
```

Comment: I thought I was working with OCaml 5, but I am really not. Wow, good to know. And you knew it immediately? Respect :) # (I got OCaml 5 on my machine, but worked over ssh on university's computer) # I am curious now if this is a deliberater machination by our prof to advertise how good OCaml 5 is and how OCaml is getting better haha

Comment: Gonna try it and let you know how it went, but seems good

Comment: I believe it is spelled Marshal? that's what I see when googling, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Worked beautifully, although took me a bit of stumbling to work out how to open the channel, get the value exposed by the module, close the channel.

Comment: My C heart would like to not open the file at runtime but bake it in statically, which is probably irrational, but would be nice to know how to. I got a really ugly absolute path for now though :/

Comment: You could bake your data in a source file by using `Marshal.to_string data []` in your code generator.

Answer (score 1):

I tried defining a list of 75,000 ints and indeed the compiler ran out of stack space during the compile. That's interesting, but there have to be some limits placed on programs I suppose.

I conjecture that your problem with the individually built-up list is that the compiler is trying to do constant folding, i.e., to create the same large list at compile time.

I was able to get a list of 75,000 ints by doing the concatenation at runtime.

In essence I defined 75 lists of 1000 ints each. Then I defined a single value of type `int list list` containing each of these separate lists.

```
let sublist1 = [1; 2; ...; 1000 ]
. . .
let sublist75 = [1; 2; ...; 1000 ]

let list_of_lists = [ sublist1; sublist2; ...; sublist75 ]
```

Then finally I have:

```
let long_list = List.concat list_of_lists
```

The main function looks like this:

```
let main () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (List.length long_list)

let () = main ()
```

When I run it I see this:

```
$ ./big
75000
```

Comment: one thing bothering me with this idea is that I will have to divide the sublists at some point, and don't know how to orchestrate it automatically, especially with a kind of rigid type system. OTOH maybe one or two unnecessary nests do not hurt and are plenty? Writing this comment I remember that I can do anything Turingly possible during generation, so it sounds like fun to do it optimally assuming some number (prolly ca 50k) is safe. Thank you once more!

Comment: Gonna investigate compiler optimization/performance and leave a note here afterwards too